# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: file inside my project

Tags: java, eclipse

when i start tomcat i get the following error:

```
   Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Core/Interfaces/ILogger
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2583)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1916)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredFields(Introspection.java:110)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadFieldsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:262)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationServletAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:136)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:66)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:328)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:778)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:299)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:94)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5105)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
```

Here ILogger.java is a file in my project.What could be wrong with my build path?WHere to start checking for teh issue?

adding ILogger.java as requested.
    package Core.Interfaces;

```
public interface ILogger {
    void Information(String info);

    void Warning(String msg);
    void Warning(String warning, String methodName);
    void Warning(String warning, String methodName, RuntimeException ex);

    void Error(String info);
    void Error(String error, String message, RuntimeException ex);
    void Error(String p, String p_2);
    void ErrorException(RuntimeException ex);
    void ErrorException(Exception ex);

    void ForceInformation(String info);
    void ForceInformation(String info, String method);

    void ForceWarning(String msg);
    void ForceWarning(String msg, String method);
    void ForceWarning(String warning, String methodName, RuntimeException ex);
    //void ForceWarning(String warning, String methodName, RuntimeException ex, StackTrace stackTrace);

    void Information(String information, String methodName);
    void Information(String information, int inEventID, short inCategory);

    void FileName(String fileName, String key);
}
```

Comment: Can you include the ILogger.java code along with the implementation? Typically, custom ILogger interfaces aren't used en-lieu of the Logger interface so seeing how you implemented it will help.

Comment: have you verified the ILogger.class file is in your .war before deploying?

Comment: the class file is present in myProj/bin directory..along with other class files.